# How to selectively place items in 2 tables using XPATH (XSLT Template)

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Im currently stuck in this homework question.

I must create 2 tables one with movies before the year 2005 and a secondary table with movies 2005 and onwards. In my code i created two tables and filled them in with the information. But I can't figure out how to make a conditional statement that places movies of year 2005 onward in one table and moves before 2005 in a second table. Im not sure if i need to create a conditional statement for both table templates or it can be done with one conditional statement that matches the criteria for both tables.

Please see my code below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Movies</title>
        <style type="text/css">
          .myTable
          {
          border-collapse: collapse;
          border-spacing: 5px;
          }

          .myTable td, th
          {
          border: 1px solid #000;
          padding: 5px;
          }
          .myTable2
          {
          border-collapse: collapse;
          border-spacing: 5px;
          }

          .myTable2 td, th
          {
          border: 1px solid #000;
          padding: 5px;
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h3>Movies Until 2005</h3>
        <table class="myTable">
          <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Director</th>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>Genres</th>
          </tr>

          <xsl:variable name="counter" select="count(movies/movie/id)"/>

          <xsl:apply-templates select="movies/movie">
            <xsl:sort select="title"/>
          </xsl:apply-templates>

          <tfoot>
            <tr>
              <td>
                Number of movies: <xsl:value-of select="$counter"/>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tfoot>

        </table>
        <br/>

        <h3>Movies 2005 Onwards</h3>
        <table class="myTable2">
          <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Director</th>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>Genres</th>
          </tr>

          <xsl:variable name="counter" select="count(movies/movie/id)"/>

          <xsl:apply-templates select="movies/movie">
            <xsl:sort select="title"/>
          </xsl:apply-templates>

          <tfoot>
            <tr>
              <td>
                Number of movies: <xsl:value-of select="$counter"/>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tfoot>

        </table>
        <br/>

        <h1>Directors</h1>
        <xsl:for-each select="movies/movie">
          <xsl:sort select="principalDirector"/>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <xsl:value-of select="principalDirector"/>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </xsl:for-each>

      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match ="movie">
    <xsl:variable name="hyperlink">
      <xsl:value-of select="url" />
    </xsl:variable>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="id"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="url">
            <a href="{$hyperlink}" target="_blank">
              <xsl:value-of select="title" />
            </a>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="title" />
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="principalDirector"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="year"/>
      </td>
      <td>
          <xsl:for-each select="genre">
            <xsl:value-of select=
         "concat(., substring(', ', 2 - (position() != last())))"
         />
          </xsl:for-each>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is the XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Movies.xslt"?>

<movies>
  <movie>
    <id>1000001</id>
    <title>The Avengers</title>
    <principalDirector>Joss Whedon</principalDirector>
    <year>2012</year>
    <genre>Action</genre>
    <genre>Adventure</genre>
    <genre>Sci-Fi</genre>
    <url>http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0848228/?ref_=nv_sr_1</url>
  </movie>
  <movie>
    <id>1000002</id>
    <title>Avatar</title>
    <principalDirector>James Cameron</principalDirector>
    <year>2009</year>
    <genre>Action</genre>
    <genre>Adventure</genre>
    <genre>Fantasy</genre>
    <url>http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0499549/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1</url>
  </movie>
  <movie>
    <id>1000003</id>
    <title>Inception</title>
    <principalDirector>Christopher Nolan</principalDirector>
    <year>2010</year>
    <genre>Action</genre>
    <genre>Mystery</genre>
    <genre>Sci-Fi</genre>
    <url>http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1375666/?ref_=tt_rec_tti</url>
  </movie>
  <movie>
    <id>1000004</id>
    <title>Gladiator</title>
    <principalDirector>Ridley Scott</principalDirector>
    <year>2000</year>
    <genre>Action</genre>
    <genre>Drama</genre>
    <url>http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0172495/?ref_=nv_sr_1</url>
  </movie>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't figure out how to make a conditional statement that places
>   movies of year 2005 onward in one table and moves before 2005 in a
>   second table. Im not sure if i need to create a conditional statement
>   for both table templates or it can be done with one conditional
>   statement that matches the criteria for both tables.

There's actually no need for any conditional statements - just use *predicates*. Try this as a guide:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:variable name="thead">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Director</th>
        <th>Year</th>
        <th>Genres</th>
    </tr>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/movies">
    <xsl:variable name="movies-before" select="movie[year &lt; 2005]" />
    <xsl:variable name="movies-after" select="movie[year >= 2005]" />
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Movies</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h3>Movies Until 2005</h3>
            <table>
                <xsl:copy-of select="$thead"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$movies-before">
                    <xsl:sort select="title"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Number of movies: <xsl:value-of select="count($movies-before)"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
            <br/>
            <h3>Movies 2005 Onwards</h3>
            <table>
                <xsl:copy-of select="$thead"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$movies-after">
                    <xsl:sort select="title"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Number of movies: <xsl:value-of select="count($movies-after)"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="movie">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="id"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="principalDirector"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="year"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:for-each select="genre">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                    <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```